# How set up test code coverage with different test levels?

Tags: node.js, testing, mocha.js, code-coverage

I'm using [nyc](http://npmjs.com/nyc) for generating Code coverage reports. I use different levels for my tests. How I can merge reports from different levels?

There is my part of my package.json

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:component",
  "test:component": "nyc mocha ./test/component",
  "test:unit": "nyc mocha ./test/unit"
},
"nyc":     {
  "extension": [
    ".ts"
  ],
  "cache": true,
  "reporter": [
    "lcov",
    "text-summary"
  ]
}
```

Comment: You can use a hosted solution to accomplish this via Codecov Flags: http://docs.codecov.io/docs/flags let me know if you have questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `nyc` and `mocha` in a sequence to achieve this effect.

With `npm scripts` this will look like :

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "coverage" : "nyc npm run test",
        "test": "npm run test:unit && npm run test:component",
        "test:component": "mocha ./test/component",
        "test:unit": "mocha ./test/unit"
    },
    "nyc": { ... }
}
```

The main idea, behind `nyc` is that it takes all the source files defined in your configuration and instruments them.

Then it runs the command after the instrumentation with modified `require`, so every command that you run from inside `nyc` will have the instrumented files as it's source.